# batch processing variable length sequences using element research RNN for Torch Lua

Tags: lua, torch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to train an LSTM model available in element research's RNN module, with phonetic transliteration data. I have training data as separate table for X and Y. Both X and Y contains each training example as tensors ie, a tensor in X contains ASCII values for each character in a sequence and a tensor in Y contains ASCII values for resulting sequence. I've created data in a form such that, for a specific example from X and Y, its perfectly arranged and padded with zeros for training. So, I could train LSTM with one example at a time. But, problem is, I don't know how to do batch training, because, each example tensor have different length.

I think, I could make it clear by this representation:

```
X{                                      Y{ 
[EEEEE00000]                            [00000MMMMM]
[EEE0000]                               [000MMMM]
[EEEEEEEE0000000000]                    [00000000MMMMMMMMMM]
.                                       .
.                                       .
.                                       .
}                                       }
```

where, EEEE.. represents input sequence and MMMM... represents output sequence..

I have not designed the model yet, because I'm thinking about a proper one that will support batch training as well. Do I wanna modify my data or should I design a model in a way to modify this data? If its on model, how could I do it?

Foot note: This LSTM must forget previous sequence after each training example. Because each example is independent. Ie, backprop should only be done for **a_single_example_length** time steps.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dataset of variable length sequences and you want to do batching. The solution is to organize your X and Y as `seqlen x batchsize` tensors where each independent sequence is separated by zeros (or tensors of zeros):

```
0 0
1 2
1 2
2 3
0 0
2 3
2 3
1 2
```

In the above example, we have sequences 1-1-2, 2-2-1, 2-2-3 and 3-3-2, each separated by a zero.

Using [rnn:maskZero()](https://github.com/Element-Research/rnn#maskzeroninputdim), the `rnn` can detect those zeros and forget the previous hidden state when detected. This effectively means that BPTT will only backpropagate for the duration of the sequence (i.e. the zeros reset the BPTT).

Comment: So, can I input sequences like this? (consider each pair as a separate raw creating a matrix [seqlen x batchsize] note: zeros are not part of the sequence, they indicates terminals of sequences )
`    00
    12
    13
    22
    02
    13
    20
    30
    00`

I think, this will be a batched sequence for this case I'm talking about.